# How Can I use SPSS to conduct a Generalized Least Square regression

Tags: time-series

I ran OLS regression on my data and found issues with auto correlation due to non-stationarity of data (time series data). I need to conduct a Generalized least Square regression as it is robust against biased estimators

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for Open Data SE. Asking in [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be better.

Comment: Vote to close this